# After a clean and complete setup of MiKTeX, there is still no Maintenance and Maintenance (Admin)

Tags: errors, miktex, console, maintenance

After performing several clean uninstallations and installations with both the basic and the complete (net) setup of MiKTeX 2.9, I still won't get any of the MiKTeX Maintenance tools (like the Package Updater (Admin) or whatever the name). My start menu looks like this:
[image]

and it seems to be missing from the directory as well.

As the console appears to be working as intended, I have already checked for updates (none to be found with the complete installation) but this does not change anything.

Surprisingly, according to my Google searches, nobody else seems to get this... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Since version 2.9, MiKTeX merged its `Package Manager`, `Maintenance` and `Update` into a single application: `MiKTeX Console`. See the official website [here](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console).

Comment: @RuixiZhang Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @RuixiZhang: Oh... well... that explains it, I guess (:
Thank you!

Comment: @TeXnician Sure thing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On April 18, 2018, the MiKTeX team announced that [MiKTeX Console is meant to replace old MFC applications](https://miktex.org/announcement/mfc-deprecation). The old applications `Settings`, `Package Manager` and `Update` in the `Maintenance` folder are now merged into one single application: `MiKTeX Console`.