# File caption.sty not found

Tags: packages

please how can I solve this problem in LaTex: Error File caption.sty not found? I have MikTex on Windows. Thank you very much.

[image: MiKTex]

[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! probably is not installed. check with "MikTeX Console" which is part of your MikTeX installation.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I found only MiKTex Update in my computer. Is this application like MikTex Console?

Comment: if have it, than you also should have Package Manager. both are now part of "MikTeX Console.

Comment: MiKTeX `Update`, `Package Manager` and `Settings` are somewhat depreciated. You should update your MiKTeX distribution from the official website and use the latest MiKTeX Console. Please have a look at [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438613/164314).

Comment: I am sorry I can not find those buttons. What should I click on?  I added a picture of MiKTex to my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Go to [this linked official website](https://miktex.org/download), download the application, and reinstall your MiKTeX. The old apps were depreciated, and sometimes package installation could not be completed automatically. It is worth having the latest software. :)

Comment: TexnicCenter (for one) does not like to be interrupted by MikTeX "choose" features.

Answer (score 4):

Usually MiKTeX can be configured to automatically download missing packages, but on my side it wasn't doing that, despite being configured to do so. However, you can still install missing packages manually in the MiKTeX Package Manager:

1. Open MiKTeX Package Manager
2. Search in the Name-box for the desired package, e.g., `caption`
3. Right-click on caption and select Install

[image]